# if there exists a sequence $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=0}$, consisting entirely of elements in $X$, which converges to $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove the Lemma:

Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $x$ is an adherent point of $X$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(a_n)^{\infty}_{n=0}$, consisting entirely of elements in $X$, which converges to $x$.

### My Attempt

$x\in \mathbb R$ is an adherent point of $x$ if and only if there exists $(a_n)\subset X$ such that $a_n \rightarrow x$. Pick $\epsilon = 1/n$ then there exists $a_n\in X$ such that $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ all $n\geq N$. $|a_n -X|\leq \epsilon$. Thus $x$ is an adherent point of $X$.

Comment: What is your definition of adherent point? And what is your question?

Comment: all this seems quite confused. not sure how you tried to use the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of the convergence of sequences, and the question is "if and only if", hence you'd have to prove $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is an adherent point of $X$, if it is in the closure of $X.$
Every open ball containing $x$ contains a point in $X.$

Prove it forward.

Suppose there is sequence {$x_n$} that converges to $x$ such that every $x_n \in X$.

$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N>0$ such that $n>N \implies |x_n-x| < \epsilon$

For any neighborhood of $x$, there is an $x_n\in X$ that is also in that neighborhood.

$x$ is an adherent point in $X.$

Now prove it the other way.

Suppose, $x$ is an adherent point in $X.$

Then in any neighborhood around $x$  ($\forall\epsilon > 0$) there exists $Y\subset X$ such that $y \in Y \implies |x-y|<\epsilon$

There exists a sequence of $y_n \in Y$ (which are also in X) that converges to $x.$  i.e. $n>N \implies |x-y_n|<\epsilon$

Note: $x$ could be an isolated point in $X$.  In which case it would still be an adherent point.  And, there would exists a sequence of {$x_n$} such that $n>N \implies x_n = x$